# Using .unique(:as ...) with numbers in Perl 6

Tags: raku

In the [docs](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/unique#(List)_routine_unique), it is explained how to normalize the elements of a list before calling `.unique`:

> The optional :as parameter allows you to normalize/canonicalize the
>   elements before unique-ing. The values are transformed for the
>   purposes of comparison, but it's still the original values that make
>   it to the result list.

and the following example is given:

```perl6
say <a A B b c b C>.unique(:as(&lc))          # OUTPUT: «(a B c)␤»
```

What if I want to make a list of rational numbers unique, comparing only their integer part? How should I call `Int` method inside the parentheses after `:as`?

```perl6
my @a = <1.1 1.7 4.2 3.1 4.7 3.2>;
say @a.unique(:as(?????))                # OUTPUT: «(1.1 4.2 3.1)␤»
```

**UPD:** 
On the basis of @Håkon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47137464/7730888), I've found the following solution:

```perl6
> say @a.unique(:as({$^a.Int}));
(1.1 4.2 3.1)
```

or

```perl6
> say @a.unique(as => {$^a.Int});
(1.1 4.2 3.1)
```

Is it possible to do it without `$^a`?

**UPD2:**
Yes, here it is!

```perl6
> say @a.unique(as => *.Int);
(1.1 4.2 3.1)
```

or

```perl6
> say (3, -4, 7, -1, 1, 4, 2, -2, 0).unique(as => *²)
> (3 -4 7 -1 2 0)
```

or

```perl6
> say @a.unique: :as(*.Int);
(1.1 4.2 3.1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to pass an [anonymous](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Perl_6_Programming/Subroutines#Anonymous_Subroutines) sub routine to `unique`. For example:

```
my @a = <1.1 1.7 4.2 3.1 4.7 3.2>;
say @a.unique(:as(sub ($val) {$val.Int}));
```

**Output**:

```
(1.1 4.2 3.1)
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Strangely, the syntax that works with `sort`, doesn't work with `unique`: `say (3, -4, 7, -1, 2, 0).sort: *.abs`

Comment: @EugeneBarsky See [Positional vs. Named](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#index-entry-positional_argument_%28Signature%29_named_argument_%28Signature%29). [`sort` routines](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/sort) (eg `multi method sort(&custom-routine-to-use)`) accept a comparison closure `&closure` passed as a **positional** arg, specifically the first one -- `[1,3,2].sort: &closure`. [`unique` routines](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/unique) accept a canonicalizing closure `&closure` if it's passed as a **named** arg, specifically one named `:as` -- `[1,3,2].unique: :as(&closure)`.

Comment: @raiph Thanks! I finally figured it out, and your explanations help me to put it in order, yet I can't understand why these two similar routines are implemented differently.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky It's partly [histerical raisins](http://catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html). cf ["the real problem is `.unique` and `.sort` having different signatures, isn't it?"](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-04-10#i_12313857). To make `sort` and `unique` consistent in this regard we'd have to deprecate the `[1,3,2].sort: *.abs` syntax and switch to `[1,3,2].sort: :with(*.abs)` in `6.d` or later. P6 is designed to make this sort of change / deprecation less painful than it is for other languages but it would still hurt. I imagine the consensus is to leave it as is for now.

Comment: @raiph A wonderful English idiom, I'll use it in future! :) Of course, there is no need to break it, I just wondered (trying to better understand), what were the possible reasons behind that decision.